# linq combine 2 tables into one list

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have 2 tables in db - one is `EmploymentRecords` one is `EmploymentVerificationRecords`

I want to query both tables and return one List

I have a Model (simplified example):

```
Public Class Record
{
  int ID {get; set;}
  string name {get; set;}
  bool IsVerification {get; set;}
}
```

I want to have some type of query in LINQ like :

```
  var records = from a in _context.EmploymentRecords
        join b in _context.EmploymentVerificationRecords on a.id equals b.id
        where a.UserID = 1
        select new Record() { .ID = a.id, .name = a.name, .IsVerification = false}
        // I also want to select a new Record() for each b found
```

see - I also want a new `Record()` added to the results for each record found in the second table , for these results `IsVerification` would be `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select everything from DB as it is selected now (but I would rather use `join/into` to do that) and then flatten results into one big collection using LINQ to Objects.

Following should do the trick:

```
var records
    = (from a in _context.EmploymentRecords
       join b in _context.EmploymentVerificationRecords on a.id equals b.id into bc
       where a.UserID = 1
       select new {
           a = new Record() { ID = a.id, name = a.name, IsVerification = false},
           b = bc.Select(x => new Record() { ID = x.ID, name = b.name, IsVerification = true })
       }).AsEnumerable()
         .SelectMany(x => (new [] { x.a }).Concat(x.b));
```